# Coloring a polyomino tiling so that no two pieces with the same color have a common point

Tags: recreational-mathematics, coloring, tiling, polyomino

How many colors are enough to color all [polyomino tilings](https://www.vicher.cz/puzzle/polyform/minio/polynom.htm) so that no two adjacent or touching polyominoes have the same color? In the following example 6 colors are required (each region has a common point with every other region). Are there tilings that cannot be colored with 6 colors?

```
5 5 6 6
5 1 2 6
5 3 4 6
5 5 6 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polyomino tilings induce [1-planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph). It was shown by [1] that these graphs are 6-colorable, but the proof is really involved and uses the same techniques as the infamous [4-colour theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem), though which much less reducible configurations. The proof is already quite involved for just proving that the graph is $7$-colorable.

Still, we can easily show that $1$-planar graphs are 8-colorable:

Let $G$ be a maximal $1$-planar graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. By removing one edge for each crossing pair of edges, we get a maximal planar graph $G'$ with $n'=n$ vertices, $m' = m-c$ edges where $c$ is the number of edges removed and $f'$ faces.

We know by Euler formula that $m'\leq 3n'-6$ and $f' = 2n'-4$ .
So $m = m'+c \leq 3n'-6 + f'/2 = 4n'-8$ (each removed edge cross two faces, on face can only be crossed by one edge)

The average degree is $\frac{2m}{n} < 8$, so there exist a vertex of degree $7$. Hence $1$-planar graphs are $7$-degenerate, so $8$-colorable. (See [2])

[1]: *Borodin, O. V.*, Solution of Ringel’s problems concerning the vertex-faced coloring of planar graphs and the coloring of 1-planar graphs, Metody Diskretn. Anal. 41, 12-26 (1984). [ZBL0565.05027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0565.05027).

[2]: *Fabrici, Igor; Madaras, Tomáš*, [**The structure of 1-planar graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2005.11.056), Discrete Math. 307, No. 7-8, 854-865 (2007). [ZBL1111.05026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1111.05026).